# Vue difference between 'value' & '_value' when outputting $ref

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to access the value of an input field that I have within a form,

however if I use v-model I get an incomplete result and if I try and log the value like:

```
console.log(this.$refs.address.value);
```

the result

> 4 Duiker Cresc

and it should be

> 4 Duiker Crescent, Sand bay, Sandbaai, South Africa

[image]

This is the Html

```
    <div class="form__group">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form__input"
        placeholder="Street Address"
        ref="address"
        required
        @change="watchAddress($event)"
        v-model="User.street_address"
      />
      <label for="address" class="form__label">Street Address</label>
    </div>
```

the question is how do I get the value of this element, note this issue seems to be caused because I am using the google maps api to auto complete the address field

```
let googlePlaces = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (this.$refs.address),
  { types: ["geocode"] }
);
```

Comment: that because v-model is actually use `oninput` to trigger the change and when google maps update the input that event not called so your data not get updated.

Comment: @elichen how would I force an update then?

Comment: if you a event when google auto complete then that when you should update the data. im not familer with google map api but im pretty sure you have this kind of event.